# Linux watchdog ping with interval longer than hardware watchdog limit

Tags: watchdog

I am running Linux on a hardware that has a 16 second hardware watchdog timer (`sunxi-wdt 1c20c90.watchdog: Watchdog enabled (timeout=16 sec, nowayout=0)`). I set in `watchdog.conf`:

```
watchdog-device         = /dev/watchdog
watchdog-timeout        = 16
interval                = 10
```

I want to ping a host with relaxed timing (every ~5 minutes) but `watchdog.conf` says that the ping test is executed every `interval`. My network link can take more than 10 seconds to come up after startup so I guess I could end up in a reboot loop.

Is there a way to relax ping timing in the watchdog daemon itself or do I need to write a custom test script?

Comment: Why not delay the loading of the wdt module until the network is up & running?

Answer (score 0):

I have set `retry-timeout = 600` in `/etc/watchdog.conf` for a timeout of 10 minutes for the ping test.
You can test the configuration without hardware reboot, before you enable the watchdog service with

```shell
sudo watchdog -F -v -q
```

against a non existing IP.

A simulated timeout results in

```
watchdog[5643]: Shutdown blocked by --no-action (error 101 = 'Network is unreachable')
```

in `/var/log/syslog`